# How to load multiple models sequentially in Ember JS route

Tags: ember.js

What is the best way to load multiple models sequentially in Ember JS?

e.g.

```
App.ProductRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function(params) {
     // first call
     this.store.find('Product');
     // second call should only be called after the first find is completed    
     var prod = this.store.find('Product', params.product_id);
     // third call should only be called after the above is completed
     this.store.find('ProductOptions', prod.get('optionId');
     return ??? 
   },
   setupController: function(controller, model){
      // how would one the set up the controllers?
   }
});
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521967/emberjs-how-to-load-multiple-models) post shows how to load multiple models in a route at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own promise, and resolve a hash.  That will be the model in the controller, no need to override `setupController` unless you want them stored on the controller somewhere different.

```
App.ProductRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function(params) {
     var self = this;
     return new Em.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject){
       // first call
       self.store.find('Product').then(function(products){

         // second call should only be called after the first find is completed    
         self.store.find('Product', params.product_id).then(function(product){
           // third call should only be called after the above is completed
           self.store.find('ProductOptions', product.get('optionId').then(function(productOption){
             resolve({
               products:products,
               product:product,
               productOptions:productOptions
               }); 
           });
         });
       });
     }); 
   }
});
```

BTW, it sounds like product options should be an async relationship on the product.

Comment: Thank you kingpin2k - you are awesome!